# Background initialization of a Virtual Disk (raid 10), can you power off completely and resume days later?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, virtual-disk

Upon setting up a new Dell Poweredge system with RAID 10, I see in System Setup --> Virtual Disk Management the Virtual Disk I created is performing a background initialization. From my understanding, this is setting up the various parity/mirror information on the disks and not modifying any real data.

During this background initialization, I can upgrade BIOS, install an OS, etc without issues. System reboots and keeps initializing. Am I able to power off this system and resume next week and initialization will just continue where it left off?

Comment: Maybe... but why would you? Is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: @joeqwerty I am setting up 50 servers with updated firmware and a few misc bios settings. Requires me to install an os and update firmware on bios/idrac/raid/etc and go into bios and make updates as well. I am only able to do 4 at a time based on hw limits. I can do everything I mentioned but end up waiting 2 hours for it to finish initializing. Obviously a huge waste of time if I can shutdown and let it pick back up next week.